# is required to install excel software in the server to import data from excel to sql server?

Tags: asp.net

one of my interview question asked by the technical team.
i have to import excel data to sql server. is required to install excel software in the server to import data from excel to sql server? I sad no need to install on server? they are asking me with out excel on server how it will read the data from excel sheet?

to read data in excel sheet from .net application is required to install excel on server?
thanks advance

Comment: Its SQL Server not Sequel server

Answer (score 1):

Excel is not required on the sql server you are importing data on, it only requires an appropriate driver.

See more here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24236.importing-an-excel-spreadsheet-into-a-sql-server-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading only `xls` files then use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 that is inbuilt with your .net framework.

If you are reading `xlsx` files then use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. The drivers for this can be download freely from Microsoft site. You don't need to install Microsoft office for interoping.

Answer (score -1):

There are many formats of Excel Data file such as .xls, .xlsx, .csv etc

For .csv format data file you don't need to have any 3 party tool on your system you can do that with .net StreamReader

Sample Code.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( <.CSV File Path> )) 
{
   while(!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
       string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().split(',');
       //TODO: Use the String array variable Line to insert 
               your records one by one into database
   }
}
```

For all other Excel formats there is a dll available. 
Go To https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

It has given all the examples of how to use it.

Comment: Your code will not work with a line like this: `123, "456", "789,012"`